# How to work out the amount of local storage your app is using on iPhone/iPad in app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, local-storage

Is there a way to get the same data that is shown in settings->usage in iOS7 inside your application?

I know I can get the overall amounts like free space and total space, but I want also to know how much of the used space is my app.

App size - size of app bundle (appreciate I can pretty much work this out on my own, just wondered if it's possible to get in app also.)
Local storage size - i.e. mbs used for file storage in app.

Hope that's clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is not convenient way of doing this on device and the way to do it was to use NSFileManager and iterate through the apps local file system each time and add all the bytes up for each file encountered in each folder to get the application size.

Answer (score 0):

I just searched a bit in the web and found two answers that may help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446579/2320456) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7688239#7688239). The first one proposes using a script, the second one explains how to find the size of a file.

Comment: The two link you included talks about Bundle size. The OP application creates and save data to the device.  He wants to know how much space his application + data is using on the device to display it to the user.

Comment: @BlackFrog is right. Appreciate you using google, but I did also try myself ;)